# How to integrate PayU using SDK 3.7 in ios?

Tags: integration, payment-gateway, payumoney

i want to integrate payment mode of payU in my app. What i have to do for inbuilt UI. There is a method given but i don't know how to make payment perms and how to use it for testing ?  please help .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the answer . My client is from columbia so the payu buz not working in columbia.